# Sequence convergence in measure space

Tags: sequences-and-series, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Consider a measure space $(Ω, F, µ)$. Let $A_1, A_2, · · · \in F$. Show that if for all $n \geq 1$, we have $A_n \subseteq A_{n+1}$, then as $n → \infty$, it holds that $µ(A_n) → µ(\bigcup_{k≥1} A_k)$.

Since $A_n \subseteq A_{n+1}$, $\mu(A_n) \leq \mu(A_{n+1})$ so $\mu(A_n)$ is an increasing sequence that is bounded by $\mu(\Omega)$ so it converges but how do I show that $µ(\bigcup_{k≥1} A_k)$ is the limit ?
It is easy to show that $µ(\bigcup_{k≥1} A_k)$ is also an upper bound for the sequence $\mu(A_n)$ but I also need to show that this is the **smallest** upper bound and that's harder.

Comment: It's weird calling a sequence "bounded by $\mu(\Omega)$" when $\mu(\Omega)$ might be $\infty$, but it is true that increasing sequences in $(-\infty,\infty]$ have a limit in the sense that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=\infty$ is a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Define $B_1=A_1$, and $B_n=A_n\setminus A_{n-1}$ for $n\geq2$. The sets $(B_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ are pairwise disjoint and
$$\begin{align}
\bigcup^n_{k=1}B_k=A_n,\qquad\bigcup^\infty_{k=1}B_k=\bigcup^\infty_{k=1}A_k
\end{align}$$
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then
$$\begin{align}
\mu\big(\bigcup^\infty_{k=1}A_k)&=\mu\big(\bigcup^\infty_{k=1}B_k\big)=\sum^\infty_{k=1}\mu(B_k)\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum^n_{k=1}\mu(B_k)\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu\big(\bigcup^n_{k=1}B_k)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu(A_n)
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $B_1=A_1, B_n=A_n\setminus \bigcup_{i<n}A_i$ for $n \geq 2$. Show that $B_i$'s are disjoint and their union is $\bigcup_{i}A_i$. So $\mu (\bigcup_{i}A_i)=\sum \mu (B_i)=\sum [\mu (A_{i+1})-\mu (A_i)]$. Can you finish? [Write down the partial sums of the last series].